# How to read text from doc or pdf in JodConverter

Tags: java, android, mobile, apache-poi

**Caused by:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.isDirectory()' on a null object reference

```java
LocalOfficeManager officeManager = LocalOfficeManager.install();
try {
  // Start an office process and connect to the started instance (on port 2002).
  officeManager.start();
  File inputFile = new File("storage/emulated/0/COVID-19/111.pdf");
  wordtext = String.valueOf(JodConverter.convert(inputFile));
} catch (OfficeException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  // Stop the office process
  OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(officeManager);
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: handbook_multi_maker.TJ, PID: 17976 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{handbook_multi_maker.TJ/TJ.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.isDirectory()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3107) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.isDirectory()' on a null object reference at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeUtils.validateOfficeHome(LocalOfficeUtils.java:339) at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager$Builder.build(LocalOfficeManager.java:169) at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager.install(LocalOfficeManager.java:78) at TJ.SecondActivity.initWebView(SecondActivity.java:132) at TJ.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:104) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because the default behavior of JODConverter is to auto-detect the office (LibreOffice or Apache OpenOffice) installation you will be working with. In your particular case, the office home directory was not found (thus null).

So, if your office installation is within a custom directory, you can use the [officeHome](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/wiki/Configuration#file_folderofficehome) property.

Here's your updated code:

```java
OfficeManager officeManager =
    LocalOfficeManager.builder()
        .officeHome("Path to your office home")
        .install()
        .build();
try {
  // Start an office process and connect to the started instance (on port 2002).
  officeManager.start();
  File inputFile = new File("storage/emulated/0/COVID-19/111.pdf");
  wordtext = String.valueOf(JodConverter.convert(inputFile));
} catch (OfficeException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  // Stop the office process
  OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(officeManager);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this because i'm not able to find any solution for word conversion and getting this error continuously while using JODConverter...